# Stack and Container having different elevations in Flutter UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In the bottom section, there is a border displayed between two container widgets,
For the above Container, I have used a Stack having two containers as children, one having black bg and the other having white, Below the stack I have displayed another container having black bg and a rounded corner on another end, The code is given below, I want to blend that two container so that they appear to be one single container.

```
Expanded(
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(37, 37, 37, 1),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.only(
                    bottomStart: Radius.circular(100)),
              )),
            ]),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(37, 37, 37, 1),
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadiusDirectional.only(topEnd: Radius.circular(100)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the grey row isn't elevation. It's because of the border of the white container. Please remove the color or put it transparent and test again.

Comment: I need the white bg for the container, Is there a way I can remove the border from the container?